# Angular FormArray insert formgroup add index 0, makes the formgroup already have data

Tags: angular

We have a Angular FormArray with multiple formgroups in it. When we create a new form group and we do

```
this.formArray.push(createEmptyFormGroup());
```

or

```
this.formArray.insert(this.formArray.length, createEmptyFormGroup());
```

Then it is working as expected. We get an formgroup at the end of the array with no values in the controls.

But we want to add the new form group at the start of the array. So we try to use:

```
this.formArray.insert(0, createEmptyFormGroup());
```

But then we get an formgroup before all other formgroups only issue is that it has the same values as the (at the time from adding) the first formgroup in that array.

So to make it more clear. We got this list:

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

If we add on at the bottom we get:

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
- {{EMPTY}}

If we add it at the top we get:

- item 1
- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

Is there someway to prevent that the new form group takes over the data of the first entry?

Comment: check your code. In [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bakzse?file=src%2Fmain.ts) I just realized works well (I imagine your createFormGroup function use an static object to create the formGroup)

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo! You really sparked my curiosity with your suggestion, so I dove back into the code. Guess what? I stumbled upon a static part that was hiding in plain sight! I kicked it to the curb and voilà, problem solved! Thanks a bunch!